# Saving a selection and showing another one on psychopy

Tags: python-2.7, psychopy

I am trying to build a decision making task by using psychopy. I have no previous experience with python or psychopy before so that's why I am kind a stuck.

I have 15 trials and I am showing a pair of pictures on each trial. Participants need to select one of the pictures by pressing left or right arrow key. After they made their selection, I want to show them their selection and ask them about why did they choose that picture.

I have created a loop in psychopy and assingned a .xlsx file for showing my pictures in an order. My problem is, I did not assign key presses to any picture. I just have key presses to end the routine. So how can I save the pictures with participant's key press in a certain trial and after present it to him\her.

Since I do not have any correct or false answer I canoot put an extra column to my .xlsx file and then set is a s correct amnswer.

How can I connect the key presses with the visual stimuli(my pictures,presented simultaneously) and store this input and use it after to show them?

[image: Screenshot of my loop]

```
    # -------Ending Routine "Deney"-------
for thisComponent in DeneyComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, "setAutoDraw"):
        thisComponent.setAutoDraw(False)
# check responses
if secimtuslar.keys in ['', [], None]:  # No response was made
    secimtuslar.keys=None
trials.addData('secimtuslar.keys',secimtuslar.keys)
if secimtuslar.keys != None:  # we had a response
    trials.addData('secimtuslar.rt', secimtuslar.rt)
# the Routine "Deney" was not non-slip safe, so reset the non-slip timer
routineTimer.reset()
```

Can I use this `trials.addData('secimtuslar.keys',secimtuslar.rt)` variable for saving and showing in another routine in the loop?

```
# -------Start Routine "bununedensectin"-------
while continueRoutine and routineTimer.getTime() > 0:
    # get current time
    t = bununedensectinClock.getTime()
    frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
    # update/draw components on each frame

    # *text_2* updates
    if t >= 0.0 and text_2.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        text_2.tStart = t
        text_2.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        text_2.setAutoDraw(True)
    frameRemains = 0.0 + 3- win.monitorFramePeriod * 0.75  # most of one frame period left
    if text_2.status == STARTED and t >= frameRemains:
        text_2.setAutoDraw(False)
```

I need to embed an useful code between these lines I think.

Answer (score 1):

The response on each trial is stored automatically in your data file at the end of the experiment. It is also available via code on each trial. e.g. if your keyboard component was named `trial_response`, then it has a `.keys` property that can be accessed in code via:

```
trial_response.keys
```

If you are going to make use of that, then this will require using some snippets of Python code. Realistically, getting help with that will be better handled via discussion on the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org rather than here, as SO is focussed more on asking and answering specific code questions, and ones that have some sort of wider relevance to other readers.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have found the data for key presses. I think I should use a code like this:  'if secimtuslar.keys == 'left' ... nexttrial.setImage()'

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question!

[image: My Loop]

I inserted two routines (nedensol & nedesag) into my loop and add an if statement in the 'Begin routine' tab

This the code of `nedensol` routine:

```
if 'right' in secimtuslar.keys:
continueRoutine = False
```

By doing this I prevent participants to see my `nedensol` routine when they pressed right on the Deney routine.

I hope this helps other people who has a similar question!